# How to pass data from one component to other component in angular 8?

Tags: typescript, angular8

In my project, I have a two-component like subheader and list. onclick event I want to pass the data from the subheader component to the list component.

this is subheader ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jobs-sub-header',
  templateUrl: './sub-header.component.html'
})
export class SubHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

 filterChange(){
this.getAllJobs({"visibility": this.visibility, "timeRequirement":this.timeRequirement,"duration":this.duration,"payment":this.payment,"experience":this.experience});  }
```

i want to pass these data to the listview component.

my listview component ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-job-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html'
})
export class JobListComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {
}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.getAllJobs();}
```

how to do this, if anyone knows please help me.

Comment: This is not a detailed question. You are asking for basic concepts easily described in a million blog posts on any generic google search like "angular component communication". Please try to google a solution or see other related questions on stack overflow before posting a new question.

Comment: @mamichels thanks for your reply. it's there on the web. but I want to pass that particular method with values..

Comment: Your question is very unspecific and filled with lot of code not relevant for the question. Do you want a exact solution in your code?

Comment: @mamichels yeah...

Comment: Refine your code , and check [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96#:~:text=Sharing%20data%20between%20sibling%20components%3A%20Sharing%20data%20between%20siblings%20can,child%20component%20using%20Input%20decorator.)